# Match parenthesis surrounded by spaces in python with regex

Tags: python, regex

Why doesn't the following code block match the parantheses?

```
In [27]: import re

In [28]: re.match('.*?([\(]*)', '  (((( ' ).groups()
Out[28]: ('',)
```

Comment: Make your second asterisk a `+`: the "non greedy" first quantifier has no reason to "give" to the second quantifier since "zero matches" is OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demonstrating my comment:

```
import re
>>> re.match('.*?([\(]*)', '   (((( ' ).groups()
('',)
>>> re.match('.*?([\(]+)', '   (((( ' ).groups()
('((((',)
>>>
```

Note - you don't even need the backslash inside the `[]` - since special characters lose their meaning. So

```
>>> re.match('.*?([(]+)', '   (((( ' ).groups()
('((((',)
>>>
```

works too...

This is because your "non greedy" first quantifier (`*?`) doesn't need to give anything to the second quantifier - since the second quantifier is happy with zero matches.

Answer (score 1):

In your case `.*?` means everything because you used `[\(]*` which means 0 or more. So changing `*` into `+` will work for you as `+` means 1 or more.

```
re.match('.*?([\(]+)', '  (((( ' ).groups()
```